# Serve CSS with HTML after authenticating with express

Tags: node.js, express

My Problem: I need to only conditionally send an HTML file (after successfull validation). This works fine but its not sending any CSS. 
I dont want to serve these as static files because as said before they are only for authenticated users.

So how would I send the CSS with this HTML file without making it public for anyone?

I also cant use a generall middleware as I have files that are public that dont require authentication. So having middleware checking for tokens on each request would break that right?

```
app.get("/admin/", (req, res) => {
    let token = req.cookies.sessionToken;

    fetch("https://authenticationAPI/admin/", {
        headers:{
            Authorization: token
        }
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {

            res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "./admin" }, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                res.end();
            });

        } else {
            res.send("Sorry, you're not an admin!");
            res.end()
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.redirect("Sorry, something went wrong there!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Whats the motivation behind protecting css? I would think protecting just the actual pages would be enough. In any case, see my answer below.

Comment: Oh just my OCD probably. Main point being though that I can protect some files but allow others. CSS or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can protect any resource by extracting your authentication logic into its own middleware and only calling next on that if the user is authenticated, or returning a 401 otherwise.

```
//Add your auth middleware before all your routes
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    let token = req.cookies.sessionToken;
    fetch("https://authenticationAPI/admin/", {
        headers:{
            Authorization: token
        }
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return next(); //allow them to go to the next route/middleware if they are authenticated

        } else {
            res.send("Sorry, you're not an admin!");
            res.end();
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.redirect("Sorry, something went wrong there!");
    });
});


//Everything form this point is protected
app.use(express.static("path/to/css/directory")); //route to your css
app.get("/admin/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "./admin" }, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: I do however have routes that dont require authentication. I implemented your middleware with the condition if the req.url starts with `/admin`. That way I allow access to everything in the public folder but once people want the admin files they must authenticate as such. My further question is would this be solved by the order of applying the middleware? As in, could I just serve everything public before all the admin stuff and make it work that way? Right now I see the only way is asking what the user is requesting as just described

Comment: That is correct. The order of middleware determines what will get protected. So, say for example you do not want to protectt he css anymore, then you can just move this line `app.use(express.static("path/to/css/directory")); //route to your css` above your auth middleware.